# Naming convention for Maven Artifacts

Tags: maven-2, naming-conventions

We are currently trying to mavenize the existing projects in our company. We have executed a POC and are currently documenting our learnings and guidelines. I have come up the following naming convention for the maven artifacts. Please share your comments on the same

Note: In our company, projectname is always unique

### For a single level multi module maven project

### Parent (pom)

- groupId : org.companyname.projectname
- artifactId : org.companyname.projectname
- version : x.x.x

eg : org.companyname.projectname:org.companyname.projectname-1.0.0.pom

### Modules (jar)

- groupId : org.companyname.projectname
- artifactId : org.companyname.projectname.modulename
- version : x.x.x

eg: org.companyname.projectname:org.companyname.projectname.modulename-1.0.0.jar

## For a multi level multi module maven project

### Parent (pom)

- groupId : org.companyname.projectname
- artifactId : org.companyname.projectname
- version : x.x.x

eg : org.companyname.projectname:org.companyname.projectname-1.0.0.pom

### SubParent (pom)

- groupId : org.companyname.projectname
- artifactId : org.companyname.projectname.subcategory
- version : x.x.x

eg : org.companyname.projectname:org.companyname.projectname.subcategory-1.0.0.pom

### Module (jar)

- groupId : org.companyname.projectname
- artifactId : org.companyname.projectname.subcategory.modulename
- version : x.x.x

eg : org.companyname.projectname:org.companyname.projectname.subcategory.modulename-1.0.0.jar

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IMO you need not include `org.companyname` in the artifactId - it is just duplicating the information already present in the groupId, thus making the artifact names longer and less readable.

**Update:** FYI, looking through the dependencies of our project, I see plenty of similar examples, e.g.

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>

<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>

<groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
<artifactId>barcode4j-fop-ext-0.20.5-complete</artifactId>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring</artifactId>

<groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
<artifactId>oscache</artifactId>

<groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-libs</artifactId>

<groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
<artifactId>connector-api</artifactId>

<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>

<groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
<artifactId>jta</artifactId>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
```

And then there are many where the group and artifact IDs are the same unqualified name, e.g.:

```
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>

<groupId>velocity</groupId>
<artifactId>velocity</artifactId>

<groupId>fop</groupId>
<artifactId>fop</artifactId>

<groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
```

But I haven't seen any having a fully qualified group ID and an identical artifact ID (which e.g. for Log4J would be `org.apache.log4j:org.apache.log4j`).

Comment: Thanks Péter. That did make sense but I was looking at the artifacts from spring and maven repositories. They all followed a similar naming convention so I too decided to follow the crowd ;-)

Comment: @Manoj, I apparently see a very different sample of IDs - see my update (and of course, decide four yourself :-)

Comment: official maven guide for naming conventions agrees with Peter :-)
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html

Answer (score 16):

Using an unqualified name for the *groupId* matching the *artifactId* (e.g. `log4j`) is an [old deprecated practice which is not recommended](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg34557.html): it's bad at the file system level, it generates "repository mess", it makes artifacts harder to find when browsing a repository (even if most people use a search engine nowadays).

The recommendation is to include your domain name in the *groupId* and I would certainly not repeat it in the *artifactId* (to my knowledge, [Spring is NOT doing that](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.3.RELEASE/) - except maybe for OSGI artifacts?).

Here is what I use:

### Parent (pom)

- groupId : org.companyname.projectname
- artifactId : root
- version : x.x.x

eg : org.companyname.projectname:root-1.0.0.pom

### SubParent (pom)

- groupId : org.companyname.projectname
- artifactId : subcategory-parent
- version : x.x.x

eg : org.companyname.projectname:subcategory-parent-1.0.0.pom

### Module (jar)

- groupId : org.companyname.projectname
- artifactId : modulename
- version : x.x.x

eg : org.companyname.projectname:modulename-1.0.0.jar

And I also use conventions for the `<description>` element to have a clean overview during reactor builds. Here is an example on a pet project:

```
$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order: 
[INFO]   Personal Sandbox - Samples - Parent POM
[INFO]   Personal Sandbox - Samples - EJB3 and Cargo Sample
[INFO]   Personal Sandbox - Tools - Parent POM
[INFO]   Personal Sandbox - Tools - Shared Verification Resources
[INFO]   Personal Sandbox - Samples - EJB3 and Cargo Sample - Services
[INFO]   Personal Sandbox - Samples - EJB3 and Cargo Sample - Functests
[INFO]   Sandbox Externals POM
```

This is heavily inspired by Vincent Massol's way to organize big builds like he did with [XWiki](http://svn.xwiki.org/svnroot/xwiki/) or Cargo.

Comment: It's not bad if I will change `groupId` for every sub-module?

Comment: It should be `<name>` instead of `<description>` to generate the output for the _Reactor build order_.