# How to name maven-module which encapsulates application functionality?

Tags: java, maven, naming-conventions

I want to move all application logic into separate JAR (maven module).

Question: what is convention to name JAR module, which  holds' all application logic and functionality? It's good to name it as `ApplicationFacade`?

Answer (score 0):

that depends more on your architecure and layering. There is no convention in maven for names like this. In simple applications you would name the module "myappname-service". In a more complex application that comes with several modules it may be something like "myappname-ordering". So it depends :)

"Facade" is more of a pattern so its not the best choice for a module name. If you refer with this name to the GUI I would name it "myaüüname-web" or "myappname-client" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that facade would be a good name, because it would means that this jar doesn't hold the implementation of services, but only interfaces (like wemu it would be a client).

You can simply name it myapp-services.

You may find some information in the following topics , although it does not deal with your real question :

- [Naming convention for Maven Artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150003/naming-convention-for-maven-artifacts)
- [Best practices in naming conventions on Maven artifactID (is there restriction?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013735/best-pratices-in-naming-conventions-on-maven-artifactid-is-there-restriction/12020832#12020832)