# How do I add third-party jars into local Maven repository?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a library consisting of 4 jars:

```
matlabcontrol-4.1.0.jar
matlabcontrol-4.1.0-javadoc.jar
matlabcontrol-4.1.0-sources.jar
matlabcontrol-demo-4.1.0.jar
```

How do I add them to the local repository so that Maven knows where sources are and where javadoc is?

Documentation here http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html is very brief and does not answer this question.

Comment: Documentation clearly mentions how to add it, which part of it you don't understand?

Answer (score 31):

The documentation clearly mentioned the way. Think your matlabcontrol-4.1.0.jar in C:> location. So move your cmd on C:> location and run following command.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=matlabcontrol-4.1.0.jar -DgroupId=org.matlabcontrol \
    -DartifactId=matlabcontrol -Dversion=4.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

If you do that, you can access your jar file with dependency, like:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.matlabcontrol</groupId>
        <artifactId>matlabcontrol</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of groupid and artifactid ?

Comment: @Masud I install the jar using same procedure and I can see the latest jar in my local maven repository but new jar is not reflecting in maven project...can u suggest something to me

Comment: @Timeless The groupId and artefactId are what maven use to find what library you want (Sort of it like the name of a class and its package, but for jar). Roughly speaking, the groupdId identify the project the artefact is part of. When importing a custom jar, you make one up. You can use the website of the organization, for example com.mathwork.matlab, or you can use a Java package name inside the jar, like org.matlab.control. Whatever you choose doesn't matter much, as long as its unique.

Comment: You might also want to add the pom with '-DpomFile=<path-to-pom.xml' if you have that available.

Answer (score 6):

Classifiers can also be specified at the command-line. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#classifier.

Javadoc and sources are just artifacts with a classifier of the same pom.

For example:

Install the main artifact

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=matlabcontrol-4.1.0.jar 
   -DgroupId=matlab -DartifactId=matlab -Dversion=4.1.0
```

Install the javadoc using the classifier javadoc:

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=matlabcontrol-4.1.0.jar 
   -DgroupId=matlab -DartifactId=matlab -Dversion=4.1.0 -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

Comment: Today I recognized that someone voted my answer down, but he/she did not leave a comment. Would be nice if a comment could be added, because if there is something wrong I would like to correct it and also learn something for myself too.

Comment: what is the purpose of groupid and artifactid?

Comment: @Timeless the purpose, here https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html is to have a better classification of your project in the repository, among other projects. Check this too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150003/naming-convention-for-maven-artifacts and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12020832/1917237